# Is Nathan Drake really Francis Drake's descendant?

Tags: uncharted-4, uncharted-series

I think that in the first three games there are no clues about it not being true but in the fourth game:

> We get to know that Drake is not his real name. But they also state that his mother did believe that Francis Drake had descendants.

So what is the answer: yes, no, or possibly?

Comment: Minor nitpick, but I am pretty sure that Marlowe indicated that his Nate's last name was not originally Drake in Uncharted 3; it wasn't a revelation in 4. His REAL last name was revealed in 4, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Wikia](http://uncharted.wikia.com/wiki/Nathan_Drake),

> In honor of their mother's belief that Francis Drake had living heirs, they adopt the "Drake" surname.

This does more than rule out his relation by name alone. This insinuates that Nathan and Sam had no reason to believe they themselves were the descendants of Sir Francis Drake. They simply believed that there were undocumented descendants and adopted the name in honor of that belief.

That said, the writers never explicitly said one way or another whether Nathan was *actually* a descendant or not.

In short, the answer is a **definite maybe** (but probably not).

Answer (score 0):

***---SPOILER ALERT---***

This is very interesting in the game. One would think that Nate is a descendant of Drake, especially how he is portrayed in the game. However, in Chapter 16 of the fourth game, they meet an old lady while treasure hunting in her mansion. She explains to the Drake brothers how she admired their mother's work.

As you said, their mother believed that Francis Drake had heirs, and she adventured to find out, all of which the old lady documented and researched. Upon finding this information out from the old lady, the young Drake brothers adopt this last name in order to honor/remember their mother's work.

It is an ambiguous topic, because as far as I can remember, Naughty Dog don't specify if Nathan is an actual descendant of Francis Drake. I guess it is just another intriguing element to the game, making it more interesting.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

No one will ever know for certain wether or not Sir Francis Drake fathered any children. What we do know is that he was a notorious womanizer in a time period far prior to the advent of birth control. For all we know Nathan and Sam Drake are indeed two of perhaps several bastard children all a direct result of Drake's sexual prowess?